# Python generate hashes with multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a simple code that loads password list into dictionary and generates hashes out of them to a new list:

```
def hash_one():
   hash_to_string = {}
   with open("wordlists/pass.txt", "r", encoding="ISO-8859-1") as file:
       for x in file:
           x = x.strip()
           result = hashlib.sha1(hashlib.sha1(x.encode()).digest()).hexdigest()
           f_result = (result)
           hash_to_string[hash] = (f_result)
           with open("hashed.txt", "a") as final:
                final.write(f_result + "\n")
hash_one()
```

I wonder how can I use `PoolProcessExecutor()` to speed up the process? Now it's reading line by line. I've tried to do some tests but I can't get it working properly. I would like to use the 16core CPU I am using.

Comment: concurrently reading/writing from files is a nightmare. Can you just hold the entire file in memory? Or perhaps split up the file?

Comment: no need, reading/writing happen on different files. And the writing is a simple append after the main computation (the hashing). One can just write a function for whatever is done in the loop and feed it to a pool of workers quite efficiently.

Comment: You can also make up some speed by not opening the output file every single time through the loop.  Any reason not to leave it open or keep the results until the end and write them once?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga there is no way to hold a file in memory that has 15+ million of lines

Comment: Do you want to speed up the reading of lines, or the generation of hashes?

Comment: @uzdisral Assuming 10 characters per line, that is 150 million characters, which is 150 MB -- that easily fits into memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can **parallelize the hashing**, but not really the reading of the files. For that you can try splitting up the original files into 16 parts and launching your original non-parallelized code (starting 16 Python interpreters).

```
import hashlib
import multiprocessing
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def do_hash(x):
    return hashlib.sha1(hashlib.sha1(x.encode()).digest()).hexdigest()

def hash_each_in_list(l):
    return [do_hash(x) for x in l]

def hash_each_in_list_parallel(l):
    n = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    parts = [l[(i*len(l))//n : ((i+1)*len(l))//n] for i in range(n)]
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        return sum(list(executor.map(hash_each_in_list, parts)), [])

l = hash_each_in_list_parallel(open('so_2020-12-08_hashes.txt').read().splitlines())
```

```
password
123456
monkey
```

```
['2470c0c06dee42fd1618bb99005adca2ec9d1e19',
    '6bb4837eb74329105ee4568dda7dc67ed2ca2ad9',
    'a5892368ae83685440a1e27d012306b073bdf5b7']
```

---

**Non-parallelized call:**

```
l = hash_each_in_list(open('so_2020-12-08_hashes.txt').read().splitlines()))
```

---

Test results on a dummy file with 10 million lines, Ryzen 5 3600 6-core processor:

- non-parallelized: 9.9s
- parallelized: 6.3s

  - without stitching the lists together at the end using `sum(parts, [])` it's 5.1s

My guess is that copying around the memory is the bottleneck here while calculating the has on the CPU is pretty fast so there is no big speedup here. (My CPU util did not go beyond 40%)